# Reducing the number of filters of a layer in SSD model, using google's Object Detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection

I am using Google's new Tensorflow Object detection API to train on my own dataset with only one class. Using all the default parameters works ok, so I want to test the perfomance of my model if I reduce the number of filters in some (and possible all) layers. My question is how can I reduce the filters of the layers of the existing `ssd_mobile_v1` model?

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the number of filters for *all* layers by by reducing the  `depth_multiplier` scalar in your config (found under the `feature_extractor` heading).

Alternatively, you can specify the number of filters in the individual layers which provide feature maps for the localization/classification layer by modifying the `feature_map_layout` in the relevant feature_extractor module.

For your example you would modify the `object_detection.models.ssd_mobilenet_v1_feature_extractor.py` module and change the `layer_depth`. The defaults are shown below.

```
feature_map_layout = {
    'from_layer': ['Conv2d_11_pointwise', 'Conv2d_13_pointwise', '', '',
                       '', ''],
    'layer_depth': [-1, -1, 512, 256, 256, 128],
    'use_explicit_padding': self._use_explicit_padding,
    'use_depthwise': self._use_depthwise,
}
```

A preferable alternative would be to create your own feature_extractor module, ensure it is imported in `object_detection.builders.model_builder.py` and modify the `type` in your config under the `feature_extractor` header.